# How to do outer join in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables;

```
table_brands - brand_id, brand_name
table_products - product_id, product_name, brand_id
```

with this query

```
SELECT B.*, COUNT(P.product_id) 
from table_brands B 
INNER JOIN table_products P 
WHERE B.brand_id = P.brand_id 
GROUP BY(P.brand_id)
```

I am getting brand detail and product count against this brand id. But I am not getting brand detail for those brands where there is no products.

I want to get all brands and product count (product count as 0) if no products available for that brand.

Can any one help me on this.

Comment: you had 'outer' in the question title but couldn't get the "left"? odd. this may help in future http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

Answer (score 1):

Use a `LEFT JOIN` like this:

```
SELECT B.*, COUNT(P.product_id) 
from table_brands B 
LEFT JOIN table_products P ON B.brand_id = P.brand_id 
GROUP BY B.brand_id
```